# How to wait for acync Observable completed at another one Observable

Tags: java, asynchronous, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have some class that has long initialization, for example Api.
My manager class load Api class async, code below

```
class MyManager{
    private Observable<Api> apiProvider
    private Api mApi;

    MyManager(Observable<Api> apiProvider){
       this.apiProvider = apiProvider;
       apiProvider.subscribe(api -> mApi = api);
    }
}
```

But client can call methods of MyManager class, that required Api instance before it was created.

```
public Observable<List<Value>> loadVlues() {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<Value>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super List<Value>> subscriber) {
            try {
                List<Value>> values = mApi.getValues();
                subscriber.onNext(values);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                subscriber.onError(e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I need that second observable first waiting for execution of apiProvider observable. 
For example in java threads there are simple *join()* operator.

What is the best way doing it with RXJava?

---

Now I solve the problem by using BlockingObservable

```
 public Observable<List<Value>> loadValues() {

    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<Value>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super List<Value>> subscriber) {
                BlockingObservable.from(apiProvider).subscribe(new Subscriber<Api>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Api api) {
                        try {
                            List<Value>> values = mApi.getValues();
                            subscriber.onNext(values);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            subscriber.onError(e);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    });
}
```

Is it the right decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be need to block at that point.

How about

```
class MyManager {

    Observable<Api> apiProvider;

    MyManager(Observable<Api> apiProvider){
       // cache so can be fetched several times
       this.apiProvider = apiProvider.cache();
    }
}
```

and then, on loadValues(), map the new observable on apiprovider observable, like:

```
public Observable<List<Value>> loadValues() {
    return
       apiProvider.map(new Func1<Api, List<Value>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Value> call(Api api) {
                return api.getValues();
            }
       });
}
```

Like @Cochi mentioned in the now-deleted answer, [BlockingObservables should be used for test/demo purposes](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observables/BlockingObservable.html), not for real functionality as they defeat the purpose of using observables.

Comment: Can you show code of loadVlues method with map operator?

Comment: @DmitriyP added

Comment: Your solution is working! But I have another one question, what can I do if api.getValues(); returns Observable<List<Value>> ?

Comment: @DmitriyP what do you mean what you can do? if you want Observable<Value>, you can flatMap it.